# TextView and EditText android

Tags: android, android-layout, components

I want to set a text view and edit text on same line in android.

As I've wrote here I should do it with linear layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/phoneTV"
        android:textColor="#f7941e"
        android:textSize="20sp">
    </TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="0.00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

but it doesn't look at all as I want to.

My goal is to reach this component

[image]

Can you please help me how to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance!

Eden Ben simon

Comment: Please upload your image to another provider, this one is full of almost naked woman as an advertisement.

Comment: You want to put a phone number in the `EditText`, so why have you set its `maxLength` to `6`?

Comment: Thanks for the fast comments, I have uploaded to another site, sorry for the bad upload before. And about the max length its just a mistake I will change it

Comment: @user3900146 I have put it directly into your post, so it's seen here without the usage of external sites and naked women and stuff :D

Comment: I will post an example that looks exactly like your image.  I really like that look. Just need a few minutes

Comment: Just posted.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @EugeneH you forgot the stroke around. Combine it with my solution and we have a winner.

Comment: Okay I didn't notice the stroke.  Let you know when I update it.

Comment: You just create a third drawable file, in the example item_holder.xml.  set the padding to 1dp and and set the stroke to the desired color.  In this case I used photoshop to fetch the color you have in your example.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? @user3900146

Comment: @user3900146 if that is the answer you are looking for or the other ones are correct.  Mark it as solved.  The check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this together because I like its simple look.

Here is the final look of it.
[image]

**layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2c2d2d"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_holder"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/item"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Phone"
            android:textColor="#f7941e"
            android:textSize="16sp">
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#bdbfc1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/item_info"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="516-678-7325"
            android:textColor="#6d6e71"
            android:textSize="16sp">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Drawable Files** Create three drawable files in the drawables folder. Used to create round corners.

item_holder.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#b9bbbe"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:radius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

item.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:radius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

item_info.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#f1f1f2"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:radius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a background for your TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the line -->
    <item android:right="-1dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#BDBFC1"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:radius="1px"
                android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And your EditText

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the line -->
    <item android:left="-1dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#F1F1F2"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#BDBFC1"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
                android:radius="1px"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Put this into your activity

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/text_view_background"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Phone"
            android:textColor="#F7941E"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvPhone"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvPhone"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvPhone"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textColor="#F7941E"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like this, you just need to fine tune it a bit ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the attribute in LinearLayout to android:orientation="vertical"

Answer (score 0):

Change orientation to vertical and use layout_weight for both of your views.
Adjust the values to obtain the desired effect. More info here: [Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Comment: I am sorry but I can not understand why to do it vertical?

Comment: I think you're right. It shouldn't be vertical, except the LinearLayout your provided is the root element of your layout file, so in portrait mode, the orientation should be vertical. I guess you can wrap your views in a relative layout, but too many inner layouts could lead to a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawable left attribute

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/name_icon_edittext"
```

Make separate image with text 'phone' and create an 9 patch image for Edittext background. I hope it will work !

Answer (score 0):

**Use dp instead px.**  It seems like a perfect place to just use a LinearLayout with orientation horizontal with a weights.
**There is no need to write 200px every time just use Match parent.**

**So go with a LinearLayout with orientation: Horizontal** unless I'm missing something here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/bgmainactivity"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phoneTV"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Phone"
    android:textColor="#f7941e"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
<!--U can use some like this to add divider -->
    <!--<TextView-->
<!--android:layout_width="1dp"-->
<!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--android:background="@android:color/background_dark"></TextView>-->


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"

    android:background="#EBEBEB"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="0.00"
    android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
```

```
**bgmainactivity.Xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#565656" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#565656" />
<padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
```

[image]

I just hope remaining denting panting  will done by your self.
 Happy Coding